# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Дети, обучающиеся дома, не уступают своим сверстникам по степени развития(,) и у них нет проблем в эмоциональном развитии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая нужна.Предложение сложное, союзное, сложносочиненное.Первая основа - "дети не уступают", вторая - "нет".

Answer (score 1):

я тоже так считаю, предложение сложноеи имеет две основы